# Application crashes with no dump file

Tags: c++, windows, minidump

I've written an unhandled exception handler for my application to create a minidump file. But I just got an user report of my application "disappearing" and no dump file was created. What class of error could cause my application to crash without creating a dump file.  I have gotten other dump files so I know my handler works.

Comment: Try something like https://github.com/chromium/crashpad instead of a custom handler.

Comment: Maybe your application didn't crash, just exit normally?

Comment: You have to call `MiniDumpWriteDump` from an external process to reliably generate a minidump.